# React Native absolute paths don't seem to work

Tags: typescript, react-native

I try to configure React Native to use absolute paths to ease the imports pain. I tried various methods and nothing seem to work for me. There's my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "lib": ["es6"],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmit": true,
        "strict": true,
        "target": "esnext",
        "baseUrl": "src"
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "exclude": [ "node_modules", "babel.config.js", "metro.config.js"]
}
```

And babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
    plugins: [['module-resolver', { root: ['./src'] }]],
}
```

I tried with, or without babel plugin. Tried different configurations I found googling. I tried adding `"baseUrl": "src"` without paths option, or `"baseUrl": "./src"`. I tried different variations of `"paths": {"*": ["./src/*"]}`, `"paths": {"*": ["src/*"]}` and so on. I tried adding `"include": ["src"]` or removing it. VS Code understands imports very well, but when I run the app, it will crash on absolute paths. Is there anything obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Two years later, any update?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `jsconfig.json` in your root folder like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

If you are using TS you can configure the `baseUrl` setting inside the `compilerOptions` of your project's `tsconfig.json` file.

So now, if your `src` folder contains a `components` one, you can do:

```
import MyComponent from 'components/MyComponent';
```

Comment: I tried exactly that, and for some reason it still doesn't work. I updated the original post to match tsconfig.json I currently have. Any ideas?